# Which packages do I need to lock to prevent update from 12.04.1 to 12.04.3?

Tags: updates

I have seen the question "How do I prevent ubuntu 12.04.1 from updating kernel and xorg to 12.04.2 and 12.04.3?", and I have read all the advised replies. I follow the instructions and in Synaptic, I locked all kernel and headers as well as all occurrences of xorg... however, after running the update and checking that no kernel or xorg package were going to be installed, I got a console only login... and the top line says 12.04.3 as Ubuntu version... so there was some upgrade that I did not want that still happened... There are so many packages that I don't know which one updated and cause the problem.
The issue is that I want to run Ubuntu for image analysis on an old system (at work, no choice and no upgrade coming soon) that need to run the AMD drivers to get the imaging software running properly. As AMD has stopped supporting the HD 3xxx series, I must stay with xorg 1.11 or 1.12 and kernel 3.4 max for the driver to run properly.
Any help appreciated!
Rv

Answer (score 1):

There is no such package. The point releases are just to prevent people from downloading 6, 12, 18 months worth of updates each time they update Ubuntu. If you use a stock 12.04 LTS installation the upgrades will take you there. Point releases are only relevant from "First Installation" point of view, upgrading the system, there are no differences. So, what package you must hold to prevent updates? **All of them.** The only way to prevent the upgrades to packages you do not want is to hold them all. If you want a certain package installed, you must use the `hold` version function that comes with APT.

I would suggest you to switch to `radeon`'s drivers if the ATI's privatives do not work. If you want to get a stock 12.04.2 image, you can download it from http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ .

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. OK, then I have no choice than to use 12.04.2 or 12.04.3... but as you know the ATI drivers do not work with Xorg>1.12 and kernel>3.4, so what do you mean by radeon's driver? When I run a normal install with 12.04.3 and search for drivers it either say no alternative driver found or does not install the open source driver...

Comment: Strangely, I followed the advices found on various other forums and this one, I remove the catalyst 13.1 that I had installed and managed to install the default drivers offered by Ubuntu, did an update.. and so far it's working! I am sometimes puzzled by Ubuntu and linux... I'll touch wood in the meantime because maybe the next update will break everything again!